# Styling Bootstrap buttons

Tags: html, css

Having some trouble with buttons on Bootstrap:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown-profile" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
      <a href="{% url "profile_update" %}" class="btn btn-default btn-sm btn-account"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
      <span class="caret"></span>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-profile">
    <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
    <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

I just want the icon to show up and when I click on it, it will give me the dropdown. I don't want any borders or anything. I hope you guys understands what I am saying.

**This is a screenshot how it looks now:**

[image]

**I just want it to display like this (not the arrow, just display it when hovering):**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/346/

```
#dropdown-profile,
#dropdown-profile:hover,
#dropdown-profile:active,
#dropdown-profile:focus,
#dropdown-profile a,
#dropdown-profile a:hover,
#dropdown-profile a:active,
#dropdown-profile a:focus{
  background: none;
  border: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  outline: none;
}

#dropdown-profile .caret {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in;
}

#dropdown-profile:hover > .caret {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Comment: The last bit to hide the down caret and only show it on hover:


#dropdown-profile .caret {
  display: none;
}

#dropdown-profile:hover .caret {
  display: inline-block;
}

Comment: @chrisheninger Thanks, didn't see that part.

Comment: That was awesome. Thank you dude!

Answer (score 2):

Check every element (each div, ul, li) with Developer Tools (in Google Chrome for example) - it will show you the CSS set for each item.

There will be some in there with borders, border-radius and box-shadow. If you either delete those or set your own CSS to set those values to 0 or 'initial', you will get the look you want!

Good luck!
ah, Johannes beat me to it.

Answer (score 1):

in the browsers developer tools, check out which of the classes applied to the button elements puts the border and shadow on these elements, then add an additional rule for the same class containing `border: none`and `box-shadow: none`

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS code I hope it will solve your issue.

```
    #dropdown-profile.btn-default {
       border-color: transparent;
    }

    #dropdown-profile a.btn-default {
       border-color: transparent;
       background: transparent;
    }

    #dropdown-profile .caret {
      display: none;
    }

    #dropdown-profile.btn-default:hover {
        color: #333;
        background-color: transparent;
        border-color: transparent;
    }

    #dropdown-profile:hover .caret {
        display: inline-block;
    }
```

[SEE EXAMPLE HERE](http://codepen.io/husain100b/pen/yeYMqJ)